# Add Helper Classes to Project By Default

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to have visual studio add my helper classes (preferably with the correct namespace) anytime I create a new project.  For example all of the extension methods, conversions etc.  Its a pain to add them every time I start a new project.

Thanks

I'm in VS2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

- create a [project template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- create a set of library

My preferred way is to create a set of library I reuse in all of my project.
I dividet it with different scope for different kind of projects:
MyLib.Core, MyLib.Web, MyLib.Winforms, MyLib.Nhibernate etc etc

I distribute them with [nuget](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) so I can easily handle update and versioning

Comment: Thanks didn't know about the template functions.  Much appreciated !